# HTML table to CSV - Angularjs Directive Not working on Edge

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, export-to-csv

I am using this excellent directive by Yuvaraj Tana here:

https://codepen.io/YuvarajTana/pen/yNoNdZ

```
enter code here
```

However it's not working on Edge, it is giving no error, and output in console is correct,  but the download popup is not being called.

How to modify it to make it more cross-browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified your directive and try this. It should work.

```
var app = angular.module('tableCSV',[]);
    app.directive('exportToCsv',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var el = element[0];
            element.bind('click', function(e){
                var table = e.target.nextElementSibling;
                var csvString = '';
                for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length;i++){
                    var rowData = table.rows[i].cells;
                    for(var j=0; j<rowData.length;j++){
                        csvString = csvString + rowData[j].innerHTML + ",";
                    }
                    csvString = csvString.substring(0,csvString.length - 1);
                    csvString = csvString + "\n";
                }
                csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
          var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
        anchor.attr({
            href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'+btoa(csvString),
            target: '_blank',
            download: 'emailStatistics.csv'
        });
        var click = new MouseEvent('click', {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': true
        });
        anchor[0].dispatchEvent(click);
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it didn't work on my Edge, what edge version you are using?

Comment: Also, a description of how and why those modifications should make a difference would be nice.